# Click on checkbox inside a button element - Firefox issue

Tags: jquery, html

I wish to know the reason that why the below JS Fiddle works well in chrome but not In Firefox. Although nesting checkbox inside button might be wrong, But I'm only interest to know the theory behind working difference between chrome and firefox in context of my JS Fiddle.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajkishoreworks/y7tqn2w2/1/)

```
$(function(){    
    $("button.tablesaw-sortable-btn").on("click",function(){        
        alert("button clicked");        
    });
    $("input#test").on("click",function(e){        
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Firefox and Chrome handle `button events` dispatching slightly differently. The way Chrome handles the `click` event in that case is that it propagates the event from `Window` through all the descendants until the `input` is reached- this is the `capture` phase, then once it reaches `input`, it `bubbles` up to `Window` passing again through all descendants. And it handles `events` depending on the different listeners that have been called in both phase. 
In your case, since the default for the trigger phase is the bubble phase, the click goes through to the input, then you call `stopPropagation`, so it doesn't bubble up, and your `click` on the `button` isn't triggered. If you set your `listener` to work with `capture` phase, you'll see that the button is triggered even if ou have `stopPropagation` on your `input`. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/evxz483h/2/

What Firefox seems to do is to simply bubble up when it reaches the `button` instead of going down to the `input`. So the `click` never goes beneath button. Note that this seems to fit with specs of `input` element, that shouldn't be a descendant of a button:

> The interactive element input must not appear as a descendant of the
>   button element.

See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html

So I guess this behavior is normal, or at least expected. Chrome has a nice way of handling it making it a bit more flexible, but maybe in some other case Firefox way might be better also.

Comment: Is this also why a checkbox inside a button doesn't change the cursor on hover on Firefox? Also, it seems that Internet Explorer has similar behavior with regards to the click event, but it does not change the cursor to "default" inside any element with "cursor: pointer", not just buttons.