# Inserting a checkbox via jQuery stops the form to submit on webkit

Tags: jquery, checkbox, webkit

I have a basic form with button and a checkbox inside it. The checkbox is loaded via jQuery like this:

```
jQuery('.markitfixed').prepend('<input type="checkbox" /> ');
```

When you click on the checkbox within the submit button (with class `markitfixed`), nothing happens on webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari...)

It works fine on Firefox.

To demonstrate this, open [jFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59r50ep5/2/) and click on the **checkbox**.

What can I do to make it work on webkit browsers?

Comment: I will bounty this question with 50 points once eligible.

Comment: I am seeing "form is working" alert in chrome  45.0.2454.101 m

Comment: Are you saying it is not working in chrome?

Comment: @Navoneel Are you clicking specifically on the **checkbox** and not the rest of the button? Note that the button works, it's just the checkbox click that doesn't work. Also, can you please test this on *Safari*?

Comment: Ah I see..But surprised where is the check change event?You are not doing anything with checkbox.I dont have firefox..is installing and see how it does work..wait

Comment: @Navoneel Not sure what you mean. If you know the fix, please edit the jsfiddle and post the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90914/discussion-between-navoneel-and-henrik-petterson).

Answer (score 2):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/59r50ep5/4/ now.It is working in chrome.

```
// inserts checkbox insire button
jQuery('.markitfixed').prepend('<input type="checkbox" /> '); 

$(document).on('click', '.mark', function () {
        alert("form is working!");
        return false;
});
```

**EDIT 1**

Now as you want to keep the submit event then do like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.mark', function () {
        jQuery('.mark').submit();
        alert("form is working!");
        return false;
});
```

**EDIT 2**

As you want to trigger some code on form submit keeping your original code intact you can do:

```
// inserts checkbox insire button
jQuery('.markitfixed').prepend('<input type="checkbox" /> ');

$(document).on('click', '.mark', function () {
       jQuery('.mark').submit();
        alert("form is working!");      


});

$('.mark').on('submit', function() {
  alert('You submitted the form!');
});
```

Updated fiddle for you [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/59r50ep5/5/).

Comment: Interesting. However, I need it to process the jQuery function 'ajaxSubmit_mark' upon click. Can you please edit your post/jsfiddle? The original trigger was: jQuery('.mark').submit(ajaxSubmit_mark);

Comment: Thank you for the update, but I need the code to trigger the **ajaxSubmit_mark()** function like the original code: http://jsfiddle.net/59r50ep5/2/ -- any chance you can make it do that and still make the checkbox work as it is in your example?

Comment: May I know what problem are you facing with my code?Why I have shown you use of .on then? It wont directly work like jQuery('.mark').submit(ajaxSubmit_mark) this anyway.

Comment: also pls dont forget to accept answer if it works for you.This will help future readers.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain this better. Please see this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4pxrd6q/ As you can see, I am triggering a specific function. Can you update that jsfiddle and change that jQuery code so that it works with your own solution? Hopefully with this, we can break the confusion between us. Thank again. And don't worry, I will mark as fixed as soon as I understand the solution with my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked on this topic? [Click on checkbox inside a button element - Firefox issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31092439/click-on-checkbox-inside-a-button-element-firefox-issue)

It looks like it is an issue in FF.

> The interactive element input must not appear as a descendant of the
>   button element.

See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.button.html